# "Path.GetFullPath" and network paths

Tags: c#, .net, path

Why does "Path.GetFullPath" behave strange when resolving paths with relative elements on a network path?
Try this small example and compare the results:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\Stay\Elim1\Elim2\..\..\SomeFolder"));  // yields C:\Stay\SomeFolder
            Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFullPath(@"\\Stay\Elim1\Elim2\..\..\SomeFolder"));   // yields \\Stay\Elim1\SomeFolder ???
        }
    }
}
```

It might be a bug or there might be some sense in it, but I don't get it.

(None of the pathes or even parts of it them really exist on my machine, so its merely a string operation)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When You use a network path the second part of the path is the *Share-name* not directory.

```
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\SomeDir\Dir1\Dir2\..\..\SomeFolder"));
```

> C:\SomeDir\SomeFolder

```
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFullPath(@"\\Server\ShareName\Dir1\Dir2\..\..\SomeFolder"));
```

> \Server\ShareName\SomeFolder

Comment: You beat me to it by 10 seconds!

Comment: Right! .net is too smart for me!